# Can WidthRequest be converted or overwritten depending on Device type(Tablet, phone or Desktop)?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

My **IOS Application** utilize **WidthRequest** all over my **XAML** code and would like to know if there is a faster way on overwriting or converting each fixed **WidthRequest** value depending on the Device?

The easiest way is to put OnIdiom in every code but will take more time to code. Example I need to do the example code below 200+ times which will take a lot of time

From :

```
<Button  WidthRequest="500"
        Text="CLOSE"
        FontSize="Large"
        Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
        TextColor="White"/>
```

To :

```
<Button Text="CLOSE"
        FontSize="Large"
        Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
        TextColor="White" >
    <Button.WidthRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <OnIdiom.Phone>250</OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnIdiom.Tablet>500</OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
</Button.WidthRequest>
```

Comment: `WidthRequest="{x:Static MyConstants.ButtonWidth}"`, as seen in [x:Static Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml-markup-extensions#the-xstatic-markup-extension). You'll set value in a static class constructor; see that link for example.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve good idea, was thinking if he want to keep it in xaml only, the solution is then to build a console parser to achieve that

Comment: Not sure I know exactly what you mean, but parser sounds like overkill. `x:Static` is simple enough xaml, so is convenient to do what that doc shows.